# How can I make a button avoid the mouse in hta?

Tags: jscript, hta

I have tried many ways to make the button avoid the mouse. I have tried all the onmouse functions, yet they don't seem to work, btw I am trying to make the button get the size of the computers screen, and make the button move all around the screen.
Here is the code that I have:

```
<body onload="WindowResize()">

<div class="align-topleft">
    <button onmouseover="moveObj(this)" id="ClickMe" class="btn" type="button">Click Me...</button>
</div>

<script>
function moveObj(obj){
var w = window.screen.width, h = window.screen.height; // width and height
newWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
obj.style.position="absolute";
obj.style.left=newWidth+"px";
obj.style.top=newHeight+"px";
}
function checkObj(event,obj){
var top = obj.style.top.split("px")[0];
var left = obj.style.left.split("px")[0];
if(top+5 > event.y || left+5 > event.x){moveObj(obj);}
}
//--></script>

<script>
function WindowResize()
{
    window.screen.width
    window.screen.height
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: avoid the mouse??? What does that mean?

Comment: That code has errors

Comment: `Math.random() * w`, `Math.random() * h`

Comment: @epascarello When mouse touches button, button moves to random position on screen

Comment: Well fix the errors in the code. That would be a good start. Developer console in the browser will point you towards the error.

Comment: @epascarello I have fixed the errors, now I just need to have the button get the size of the screen and go to a random spot on the screen. Could you help me with that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window

Comment: @epascarello I have did that but it does not want to resize and when I hover my mouse over it, the button disappears. How would you do this?

Comment: @epascarello I just found out about the function _**`window.moveTo()`**_ could I use this to move the window to the button and make it visible? If so, how?

Comment: How is this question related to vbscript? Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question, it practically doesn't make any sense. "_make the button get the size of the screen, and make the button move all around the screen_" There won't be much room wherein to move, if the button fills the entire screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you make use of the `HTA:Application` option `windowState=maximize`. You also need an adjustment after each random to ensure the entire button is on screen. Here's the cleaned up code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<hta:application
  id=oHTA
  windowState=maximize
  border=none
  scroll=no
>
<style>
.btn {width:100px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>    
var w = window.screen.width, h = window.screen.height;

function moveObj(obj){
  newWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
  newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  if(newWidth>w-100){newWidth=newWidth-100;}
  if(newHeight>h-20){newHeight=newHeight-20;}
  obj.style.position="absolute";
  obj.style.left=newWidth+"px";
  obj.style.top=newHeight+"px";
}
function checkObj(event,obj){
  var top = obj.style.top.split("px")[0];
  var left = obj.style.left.split("px")[0];
  if(top+5 > event.y || left+5 > event.x){moveObj(obj);}
}
</script>

<div class="align-topleft">
    <button onmouseover="moveObj(this)" id="ClickMe" class="btn" type="button">Click Me...</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note**: Press `Alt-F4` to exit